# How to pause a button in tkinter so it doesn't work for 10 seconds?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, customtkinter

I try to program a thing where when buttons is pressed the names of the person who's the button belongs to will appear on a screen. To do this I use tkinter to get the buttons in my program before my friend has build them irl. The code is long way from done but I'm stuck on a problem. When a person presses their button their name appears on a screen, then when they press again the name will disappear. Then what I want to create is that if the name has disappeared the person shouldn't be able to get their name back on the list for 10 seconds. So how do I do that?

(I just want to say that my code might not be the most optimal since I only have taken a small course in python a year ago)

```
from os import system
import customtkinter
import time

def buttons(typeOfMessage , userName):
    if (typeOfMessage == "student"):
        if userName not in activeList:
            activeList.append(userName)
        elif userName in activeList:
            activeList.remove(userName)    
    elif (typAvMeddelande == "lärare"):
        if (len(activeList) > 0):
            activeList.pop(0)
    printbutton(activeList)


def whichButton(m):
    "talar om vilken knapp"
    incomingMessage = m
    typeOfMessage, userName = incomingMessage.split(",")
    buttons(typeOfMessage,userName)

def printbutton(list):
    print(list)

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create window
app.geometry("400x240")

def setupscreen():
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
    app.geometry("1024x640")

# Create student button
button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="hampus", command= lambda m="student, hampus": whichButton(m))
button1.pack()

#Create teacher button
button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="teacher", command= lambda m="teacher, namn": whichButton(m))
button2.pack()

# Create second syudent button
button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="emma", command= lambda m="student, emma": whichButton(m))
button3.pack()

text_1 = ""
activeList = []
app.mainloop()
```

I have tried to use time.sleep() and after() but both of them pauses the whole code and that's not what I want

Comment: `app.after` will definitely not pause the code.  Show us what you tried.

Comment: use a variable to tell if it´s active or not, then `time` to check how much time has passed, if it's less than 10 seconds return the function attached with the click of that button without doing anything.

Comment: This is how i did it:                                                                                                                    def disable_button(button):
    botton.configure(state=customtkinter.DISABLED)
    app.after(5000, enable_button(knapp))  # Re-enable the button after 10 seconds

def enable_button(button):
    button.configure(state=customtkinter.NORMAL)

Comment: @kallberg It is better to update your code in the question instead of posting the code in comment which is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is option, to pause button usage by method. What I would do, is create variable in your method with stored timestamp of "click button" time. Then, next time when user wants to click button, your code should check first if 10 sec boundry passed after saved timestamp, you can do that with usage of datetime lib.